# Regexp on specific URL

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of URLS like this :

```
http://www.toto.com/bags/handbags/test1/
http://www.toto.com/bags/handbags/smt1/
http://www.toto.com/bags/handbags/test1/test2/
http://www.toto.com/bags/handbags/blabla1/blabla2/
http://www.toto.com/bags/handbags/smt1/smt2/
http://www.toto.com/bags/handbags/smt1/smt2/testing/
http://www.toto.com/bags/handbags/smt1/smt2/testing.html
```

What I want here is to only take URLS like

```
http://www.toto.com/something/else/again/more
```

Restricted to that, not taking if there is more.

Can you help me out ? :)

Comment: It's not clear what the pattern is. Which URLs in the list are valid?

Comment: Edit : Bad of me ! The 3rd ,4th and 5th ones !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate regex is:

```
^http://www.toto.com/(\w+/){4}$
```

Example of filtering:

```
>>> for line in lines:
...     if re.match(r'^http://www.toto.com/(\w+/){4}$', line):
...         print line
... 
http://www.toto.com/bags/handbags/test1/test2/
http://www.toto.com/bags/handbags/blabla1/blabla2/
http://www.toto.com/bags/handbags/smt1/smt2/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

https://regex101.com/r/gK6hR3/1

but add `$` at final

```
http:\/\/www\.[a-zA-Z.-]+\/[a-zA-Z-]+[\/]{0,1}[\.a-zA-Z-]{0,}
```

so:

```
http:\/\/www\.[a-zA-Z.-]+\/[a-zA-Z-]+[\/]{0,1}[\.a-zA-Z-]{0,}$
```